# Creating a new instance of n mostly unknown type

Tags: c#, generics, oop

I'd like to write a generic *method* that creates a new instances of a specified Type. I tried

```
protected T CreateNew<T>()
    where T : new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

This works, but only if I specified the type at compile time, just like

```
var x = CreateNew<Point>();
```

The point is, that I need to do something like this

```
ISomeInterface inter;
if (selection == 1)
    inter = new SomeClass();
else
    inter = new SomeClass2();
// ...
ISomeInterface inter2 = CreateNew<typeof(inter)>();
```

where SomeClass implements ISomeInterface.
But this fails to compile as CreateNew() needs an actual type specified. I don't know if it's possible to provide something like that at runtime, but the above code fails to compile.

So I have an instance of an unknown reference type and I need to create several instances of the same type.

Does anyone know a technique to achive this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a lambda:

```
Function<ISomeInterface> creationDelegate;
if (selection == 1)
    creationDelegate = () => CreateNew<SomeClass>;
else
    creationDelegate = () => CreateNew<SomeClass2>;
ISomeInterface inter = creationDelegate();

// ...
ISomeInterface inter2 = creationDelegate();
```

I can't see the benefit of using the CreateNew method in this case based on your example code, but I'm assuming that your "real" code is more sophisticated.

Answer (score 10):

The point of generics is to provide a mechanism whereby code can be reused for different types when the type is known at *compile*-time. In this case, you don't know the type at compile-time.

I suggest you use `Activator.CreateInstance(inter.GetType());`

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I was just confused about generic methods, as I guess I did not correctly understand something about generics written in C# in a nutsheel that stated generics can be reused at runtime (unlike C++ templates)

Comment: Yes, generic types in .NET *are* reused at execution time (i.e. the code is only defined once) but the type has to be *chosen* at compile-time (leaving aside reflection).